# Execute a compiled file using PHP

Tags: php

I have an executable which i wish to execute using PHP.
I am using centOS as my server. I created a PHP file execute.php with following code in it:

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec("/var/www/html/myfolder/a.out");
?>
```

I have also give executing permission to user **apache**

Still php is not able to execute my file when i browse to execute.php

**EDIT:** I am able to execute the file using terminal -> `php execute.php`

**EDIT-2:** A little progress. It's giving me permission issue error now.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The fact that the program is written in C++ has nothing to do with the question. I removed the [C++] tag, you should remove the first couple of lines from your question.

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    system("./a.out");
?>
```

Comment: Only works in terminal when i write: php execute.php which calls this function. It doesn't work if user goes browses to execute.php using web browser

Comment: Not getting any error. If i print anything before or after this line, it gets printed.

Comment: Is `/var/www/html/myfolder/a.out` executable by world?  Can you run it on the command line?

Comment: Have you tried `system(a.out);` since you' (presumably) already in `myfolder`?

Comment: OK, just see if you can get this to work: `system("ls /tmp"); `

Comment: It doesn't work if browse to file from web browser but if i type "php execute.php" in terminal, it runs!

Comment: If just running a PHP script that does `system("ls");` doesn't work in your browser, then your webserver is configured in such a way as to prevent you from running `system`.

Comment: Is there anyway to bypass it? I just bought a VPS and it might be misconfigured

Comment: You'll need to talk to your host and/or hire a devops guy who can support your system.

Comment: I just executed `system("ls")` and it worked! Must be some other issue

Comment: Try `system("./a.out"); `

Comment: It's a permission issue. I am getting error permission denied if i use `exec("./a.out 2>&1",$output); `

Comment: Please try what I am suggesting above - `system("./a.out");`  Maybe even do an `echo getcwd();` to be sure you are in the directory you think you are in.

Comment: `echo getcwd()` works but `system("./a.out")` doesn't... I have deduced it's a permission error. I am trying to fix it as of now.

Comment: See if the apache log has any messages.  There MUST be a log somewhere that will give you the clue you need.

Comment: `Array ( [0] => sh: ./a.out: Permission denied ) ` -> I am getting this error

Comment: Does the `getcwd()` call say you are in `/var/www/html/myfolder/`?  Change the permissions of a.out to 777.

Answer (score 0):

write like this-

$value = shell_exec('/var/www/html/myfolder/a.out');
echo $value;

and also note this function is disabled when php runs in safe mode.

Comment: This is the same as I wrote. I don't think it will make a difference.